# How to delete rows from two separate html tables parallelly using index value in jQuery asp.net c#

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a `Add` button in my page and if I click on that `Add` button some required data will add(clone) to two separate html tables parallelly in the first table I have a `delete` button only so if I click on that `delete` button the same row of two tables rows should delete(using index).

Here is my all script :-

Asp.net code is :-

```
 <%-- Table 1 --%>
<table class="table-bordered table" id="EntryParametersTableDataID">
<thead>
<tr>
<th height="30" nowrap="">Symbol
</th>
<th nowrap="">Instrument
</th>
<th nowrap="">Exp Date
</th>
 <th nowrap="">Strike Price
</th>
<th class="text-center" nowrap="">Action
</th>
<th class="text-center" nowrap="">Qty
</th>
<th class="text-center" nowrap="">Delta
</th>
<th class="text-center" nowrap="">Price
</th>
 <th class="text-center" nowrap="">Strike Type
</th>
<th class="text-center">Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>

 <%-- Table 2 --%>
 <table class="table-bordered table" id="EntryParametersTableRightDataID">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="text-center" height="30" nowrap="">Type
</th>
<th nowrap="">EXIT
</th>
<th class="brdbot0 text-center" nowrap="">TGT
</th>
<th class="brdbot0 text-center" nowrap="">SL
</th>
<th class="text-center" nowrap="">TRAIL TGT
</th>
<th class="text-center" nowrap="">TRAIL SL
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Adding Rows dynamically to html table using `Add` button

Sample code is :-

```
$('#btnAdd').on("click", function (e) {

   function AddTableRowsToTable(initialsymbal, inst, exdate, lsize, delta, ltp, sprice, optionsdata, ddlExitoptsdata, ddlSToptsdata, classbs) {
    var ddlType = '';
    var ddlExit = '';
    var ddlStrikeType = '';

    ddlType = "<select class='typeselect' id='ddltypeauto'>" + optionsdata + "</select>";
    ddlExit = "<select class='exitselect' id='ddlexitauto'>" + ddlExitoptsdata + "</select>";
    ddlStrikeType = "<select class='striketypeselect' id='ddlstriketypeauto' disabled=''>" + ddlSToptsdata + "</select>";
    if (initialsymbal != '' && inst != '' && exdate != '') {

        var bclass = "";
        var sclass = "";
        if (classbs.toLowerCase() == "buy") {

            bclass = "activebcolor";
        }
        else if (classbs.toLowerCase() == "sell") {
            sclass = "activescolor";
        }

       var dynamicTR = "<tr><td><span class='pd-price'><input type='text' disabled='' id='EntryParameters_symbol' value=" + initialsymbal + "></span></td><td>" + inst + "</td><td>" + exdate + "</td><td> <input type='text' id='EntryParameters_strikeprice' disabled='' value=" + sprice + "></td><td> <button id='btnbuy' class= 'btn-buy " + bclass + "'>B</button><button id='btnsell' class= 'btn-sell " + sclass + "'>S</button></td><td> <input type='text' class='qtyclass' value=" + lsize + "></td><td> <input type='text' id='EntryParameters_Delta' disabled='' value=" + delta + "></td><td> <input type='text' id='EntryParameters_ltp' class='ltpclass' disabled='' value=" + ltp + "></td><td>" + ddlStrikeType + "</td><td> <button class = 'btn btn-danger btn-sm'> delete </button></td></tr>";

        $('#EntryParametersTableDataID tbody').append(dynamicTR);

        $('.btn-buy').click(function () {
            
            return false;
        });
        $('.btn-sell').click(function () {
           
            return false;
        });

        var trd = "";
        trd += "<tr>";
        trd += "<td>";
        trd += ddlType;
        trd += "</td>";
        trd += "<td>";
    trd += ddlExit;
    trd += "</td>";
        trd += "<td class='text-center txtdisable'><span><input type='text' maxlength='9' onkeypress = 'return Neg_Pos_Dot_Nmbr_Acpt();' id='EntryParameters_tgt' disabled='' class='tabletwotextbox'></span></td>";
        trd += "<td class='text-center txtdisable'><input type='text' maxlength='9' onkeypress = 'return Neg_Pos_Dot_Nmbr_Acpt();' id='EntryParameters_sl' disabled='' class='tabletwotextbox'> </td>";
        trd += "<td class='text-center txtdisable'><input type='text' maxlength='9' onkeypress = 'return Neg_Pos_Dot_Nmbr_Acpt();' id='EntryParameters_tt' disabled='' class='tabletwotextbox'> </td>";
        trd += "<td class='text-center txtdisable'><input type='text' maxlength='9' onkeypress = 'return Neg_Pos_Dot_Nmbr_Acpt();' id='EntryParameters_ts' disabled='' class='tabletwotextbox'> </td>";
        trd += "</tr>";
        $("#EntryParametersTableRightDataID tbody").append(trd);

    }
    else {

        alert('Something Went Wrong ! Pleae Try Again After Sometime.');
    }
  }
})
```

Deleting rows parallelly from two html tables

Code :-

```
$("#EntryParametersTableDataID").on("click", ".btn-sm", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        let text = "Are you sure you want to remove this script?";
        if (confirm(text) == true) {

            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            var rowIdx = $(this).closest("tr").index();
            //alert(rowIdx);
            removeRowFromTable($("#EntryParametersTableRightDataID tbody"), rowIdx);
        }
        else {

            return false;
        }
    });

    function removeRowFromTable(table, rowIdx) {

        //alert('1');

        var emptyrows = "<tr><td colspan = '10' class='text-center'>No Records Available</td></tr>";
        var emptyrows_1 = "<tr><td colspan = '6' class='text-center'>No Records Available</td></tr>";


        table.find("tr").eq(rowIdx).remove();

        if ($('#EntryParametersTableDataID tbody').children().children().length == 0) {

            $('#EntryParametersTableDataID tbody').append(emptyrows);
            $('#EntryParametersTableRightDataID tbody').append(emptyrows_1);
        }
    }
```

By using this above code if I delete the first row it is not deleting same index value of second table properly see the image once

Deleting the first row

[First row deleting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cCqZ.png)

Now clicking on the delete button of first table, first row and it is deleting correct row of first table but in the second table deleting the last row (wrong index selecting)

See the example image :-

[Deleting wrong index row of second table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVsqn.png)

I'm very new to jQuery.

Suggest me where I did the mistake and how to achieve this.

I Appreciate your patience with me.

Comment: In your `//alert(rowIdx);`, what was shown?  It's odd because you `.remove()` the row in the line above so there should not be a row to get the rowIndex from.   Move the `.remove()` row after getting rowIdx

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you `.remove()` the row *before* you get its `.index()`.  As the row no longer exists, the `.index()` is -1.

A negative index passed to [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/#eq-indexFromEnd) will count from the end instead of the start.

Here's a snippet confirming the -1:

```js
$("#b").click(function() {
  console.log("before remove", $(this).closest("tr").index());
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  console.log("after remove", $(this).closest("tr").index());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td><button id='b'>click me</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

In your case this is a case of changing

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
var rowIdx = $(this).closest("tr").index();
```

to

```
var rowIdx = $(this).closest("tr").index();
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```